# PHP print multiple row data

Tags: php, mysql

I put telephone number in MySql database like this :

```
  id  |           number              |

   1  | 123456789-987654321-987456123 |
   2  | 858555588-859654744-965854777 |
   3  | 369587774-369855214-369852147 |
```

now i need to print for each id list of each telephone number like this:

```
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="phone[]" value="<?PHP echo  $row['phone'];?>" />
```

i think first separated using `explode()` function and than print `array();`

how to can i print this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `explode()` to break the string apart at the dash. Then just loop through the array of numbers echoing out each one as the value of the input.

```
$numbers = explode('-', $row['number']);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
?>
    <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="phone[]" value="<?PHP echo  $number;?>" />
<?php
}
```